# how i can handle date in path

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

i want test api of my project.
i have  Article model that have DateField that fill automatic and certainly each time save date.today()
so if i run this line of test code today it run correctly but future days  will run incorrectly

```
 response=self.client.get("/api/v1.0.0/blog/archive/en-2021-01/")
```

how i can change  the date part of above line of code dynamically.I mean part "en-2021-01" of the above code .I also tested it with a variable but it did not work.like this

```
edate=str(date.today())
response=self.client.get("/api/v1.0.0/blog/archive/en-edate/")
```

i do not know how changed it to work

Thanks for trying to help me

Answer (score 0):

hope you are using unittest...

for this purpose...
i think easiest solution during testing is use something like:

https://pypi.org/project/freezegun/

it mock your datetime and then your test run with specific date.. and always be success.

Just lead the example in the library.